# Is there a way to treat dual carriageways as a single road?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On my map when you drop a pin it calls DirectionsService to find the route from the previous pin using the latLng of the markers.  That works fine except with dual carriageways, where it essentially treats both sides of the road as separate one-way ones.

So if you click to drop the pin the wrong place – which without zooming in tightly and being very careful you have no control over – you get routes that feature unnecessary loops to change sides of the road.

Although this seems to me like an understandable and common problem, I cannot see any option to tell the directions service to treat them like a single road, which is how they are drawn on the map anyway.  Nor by searching have I been able to find any references to this problem, which surprised me.

So is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Write code to detect the "loop" and adjust the marker appropriately.  Not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: It does not sound it! Using BICYCLING as the travel mode does not have this problem, presumably as you can walk a bike across the road. Unfortunately it has its own weird loops, seemingly whenever it gets the chance to go off road. Dropping a pin by a park containing paths it will usually go a longer route via those than along a road.